# Sitecore Fieldmap Configuration Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, solrnet

I am getting the following error after I followed the installation of Sitecore SOLR for 8.1. After changing all the lucene configs to disabled, and the solr ones to enabled, and then added this in the Global.asax

```cs
public void Application_Start()
{
  this.Container = new WindsorContainer();
  var startup = new WindsorSolrStartUp(this.Container);
  startup.Initialize();
}
```

the minute I add those lines above, I get this error:

> Could not find property 'fieldMap' on object of type: System.String
>   [InvalidOperationException: Could not find property 'fieldMap' on
>   object of type: System.String]
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[]
>   properties) +2402
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred,
>   IFactoryHelper helper) +643
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +275
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +579
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +137
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +109
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +120
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred,
>   IFactoryHelper helper) +552
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +275
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +1013
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred,
>   IFactoryHelper helper) +552
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +275
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +579
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration()
>   +266    Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.get_Cores()
>   +92    Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.WindsorSolrStartUp.Initialize()
>   +44

Does anyone have an idea why this would happen? I tried replacing config files from a fresh 8.1 but still no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm you are using the correct SOLR support libraries for 8.1

Comment: Is there an 8.1 support library? I downloaded it from Sitecore for 8.1 and in the readme it says 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there was one folder where I left out a .disabled for Lucene. After doing this, it worked. Ooops!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any code in Global.asax , Just make sure that your Global.asax have the following tag in header only:

```
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.WindsorApplication" %>
```

Checkout [this link](https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/search/solr/Configuring-Solr-for-use-with-Sitecore-8/)